# superellipse with pdfliterals

Tags: pdftex, plain-tex, presentations

I don't know if this is possible, since I know nothing about PDF literals, so can I draw a superellipse with `\pdfliteral`s, and how? I'd like to write a presentation theme for [lecturer](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lecturer) which draws a nice superellipse as a frame. Suggested readings to understand the PDF literals involved are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
\pdfliteral{q 1 j 1 J 10 0 m 2 2 2 2 0 10 c -2 2 -2 2 -10 0 c 
              -2 -2 -2 -2 0 -10 c 2 -2 2 -2 10 0 c S Q}

\vskip15pt
Or convex alternative:
\vskip15pt

\pdfliteral{q 1 j 1 J 10 0 m 10 8 8 10 0 10 c -8 10 -10 8 -10 0 c
              -10 -8 -8 -10 0 -10 c 8 -10 10 -8 10 0 c S Q}
```

A short description of the literal commands is in my article [Jednoduchá grafika PDF primitivně](http://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/bulletin/pdfgrafika.pdf). But sorry, it is in Czech language only. Ovals are mentioned here as an example, no exactly superellipse.

Commands used in this example: `q` -- push graphic state, `Q` -- restore graphic state, `1 j 1 J` -- rounded corners, `10 0 m` move current point to the given coordinates, `10 8 8 10 0 10 c` -- prepare bezier curve from current point around 10 8 control point and 8 10 control point to 0 10 final point, `S` -- stroke prepared curves.

Comment: Nice fish; now I'd like to understand how to use the rod... As I said, I want to draw a rather large, probably oblong, convex ellipse. I think I see how you do draw the curve, but the meaning of the single letter commands is obscure to me.

Comment: I suspected you were "faking" the superellipse with bezier curves. I'm fine with that. Now, iiuc, the units should be millimeters, right?— Aside: if you wrote for a wider audience, your papers could be instant hits, you know?

Comment: Of course, the superellipse is circle for example when n=2, a=b. And circles are commonly "faked" with bezier curves in PDF literals. The units are in bp by default. You can change this by `cm` command (transformation matrix). I don't understand well your second notice: what does mean "papers could be instant hists". How to realize this?